# Kernel panic MacBook Pro 2017 keep restarting when starting android studio or Intellij

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

this is my full report can someone help me i want to know if it is possible to fix that ?

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80060652fa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800600a348, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff7f80179904, CR3: 0x00000002617ba053, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000005e64, RBX: 0x0000000000000003, RCX: 0x00000000000000c0, RDX: 0xffffff80068c42c0
RSP: 0xffffff81193f2f20, RBP: 0xffffff81193f2f60, RSI: 0xffffff80068c4200, RDI: 0xffffff80201080a8
R8:  0x00000000fff0ffff, R9:  0x000000000000004d, R10: 0xffffff80201080a8, R11: 0xffffff7f80000000
R12: 0x03fffffe021a310b, R13: 0xffffff7f80179900, R14: 0xffffff80200dd970, R15: 0xffffff80200eb970
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff800600a348, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff7f80179904, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 2, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81193f2980 : 0xffffff8005f3bb2b 
0xffffff81193f29d0 : 0xffffff80060734d5 
0xffffff81193f2a10 : 0xffffff8006064f4e 
0xffffff81193f2a60 : 0xffffff8005ee2a40 
0xffffff81193f2a80 : 0xffffff8005f3b217 
0xffffff81193f2b80 : 0xffffff8005f3b5fb 
0xffffff81193f2bd0 : 0xffffff80066d2aa9 
0xffffff81193f2c40 : 0xffffff80060652fa 
0xffffff81193f2dc0 : 0xffffff8006064ff8 
0xffffff81193f2e10 : 0xffffff8005ee2a40 
0xffffff81193f2e30 : 0xffffff800600a348 
0xffffff81193f2f60 : 0xffffff8005ffcacf 
0xffffff81193f3010 : 0xffffff8005ffc6d6 
0xffffff81193f33b0 : 0xffffff8005fc231a 
0xffffff81193f3420 : 0xffffff800665353d 
0xffffff81193f3530 : 0xffffff80066513b9 
0xffffff81193f3560 : 0xffffff7f88e4d73f 
0xffffff81193f38b0 : 0xffffff7f88e4b0bb 
0xffffff81193f3990 : 0xffffff7f88e1af62 
0xffffff81193f3a20 : 0xffffff7f88e244dc 
0xffffff81193f3a80 : 0xffffff7f88e25ee9 
0xffffff81193f3ac0 : 0xffffff800666739b 
0xffffff81193f3b10 : 0xffffff7f88e260e2 
0xffffff81193f3b60 : 0xffffff8006670443 
0xffffff81193f3ca0 : 0xffffff8006022d12 
0xffffff81193f3db0 : 0xffffff8005f419d8 
0xffffff81193f3e10 : 0xffffff8005f18635 
0xffffff81193f3e70 : 0xffffff8005f2f0e5 
0xffffff81193f3f00 : 0xffffff800604b575 
0xffffff81193f3fa0 : 0xffffff8005ee3226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:

         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.3.1)[66992525-3204-3CB0-8F03-4B70031B1CF2]@0xffffff7f88dfa000->0xffffff7f88ebdfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[A243D030-19AC-30AA-AC70-6C786DF9E6CE]@0xffffff7f8704c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[ADD485B5-3EF8-37C4-B3C5-F86326E497A4]@0xffffff7f8692f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.6)[42377B3B-D14A-368E-820F-07E7EA666198]@0xffffff7f87410000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(569.4)[1F9B5D88-52DB-3A16-8373-4F608A3CB2D8]@0xffffff7f86c1f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[988360A2-2E10-3014-A119-BE81BC045A10]@0xffffff7f86d81000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
19D76

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005d00000
System model name: MacBookPro14,1 (Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C)
System shutdown begun: NO

Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)


System uptime in nanoseconds: 83606510813

last loaded kext at 7255507095: >AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f895b9000, size 32768)

loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
com.frescologic.ProxyFramebuffer    1.3.1
com.frescologic.ProxyVideoCard  1.3.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.2
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.7.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.7.2
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.7.2
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>eficheck   1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.4
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.3f5
>!ABacklight    180.1
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.4
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.424
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.81.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  4.7.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.3f5
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.7.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.7.2
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.3.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.5
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AActuatorDriver   3430.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.3f5
|IO!B!F 7.0.3f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.3f5
>!AMultitouchDriver 3430.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3430.1
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.80.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```